# Any Mirror and Lens effects .Net library for Silverlight or WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, image-processing, effects

Any Mirror and Lens effects .Net library for Silverlight or WPF?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean reflections?

Comment: What I meant is distortion effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure they contain the specific effects you want, but you could have a look at these pixel shader effects libraries:

- http://wpffx.codeplex.com/
- http://fx.codeplex.com/
- http://wpfshadereffects.codeplex.com/

Also, see [this blog post](http://johnstewien.wordpress.com/2006/06/23/wpf-lens-effect-panel/) for a lens effect.

For the mirror effect, there are a lot of results in Google... The easiest way is probably to duplicate the item to mirror and apply a `ScaleTransform` with a negative X or Y scale factor.